# TFS Online Build with Grunt (Webproject)

Tags: tfs, msbuild, gruntjs, azure-devops

I've a Sharepoint Web Project which I want to build in tfs online with grunt tasks.
Finally I made the build work, grunt is also executing (I can see it in the Build logs). But when I take a look to the artifacts drop folder, there are files missing that the grunt script should create. F.e. I should have a CSS/output.css file. But it is not in the published artifacts. What I'm making wrong? The grunt task is executed directly before the msbuild task. Locally the grunt task works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Solved. The CSS/output.css file must be included in the solution.
That means: Create this file locally and include it in the project. Then the grunt task will overwrite it on the tfs online build.